# R plot legend Error in plot.xy(xy, type, ...) : invalid plot type

Tags: r, plot, legend

When I want to add legend to a plot, it has Error in plot.xy(xy, type, ...) : invalid plot type, and the plot has no points showing up. Without legend and directly using pch, I'm able to get the points on the plot. Anything wrong in the code? Thanks.

```
plot(c(farm.metadata$coordinates["Longitude"],merraLoc$Global.Longitude,ruc.points$Global.Longitude),
c(farm.metadata$coordinates["Latitude"],merraLoc$Global.Latitude,ruc.points$Global.Latitude),
xlab="Latitude",ylab="Longitude", 
legend("bottomright",c("Farm","Merra points","Ruc points-closest","Ruc points",pch=c(9,rep(19,4),20,rep(4,3)))),
main=paste("MERRA, RUC, and FARM Coordinates For: ", farm.metadata$farm.name, sep=""))
dev.off()
```

Answer (score 1):

you have wrong parentheses and have to get legend out of plot

```
plot(c(farm.metadata$coordinates["Longitude"],merraLoc$Global.Longitude, ruc.points$Global.Longitude),
 c(farm.metadata$coordinates["Latitude"], merraLoc$Global.Latitude, ruc.points$Global.Latitude),
 xlab="Latitude",ylab="Longitude",
 pch=c(9,rep(19,4),20,rep(4,3)), main=paste("MERRA, RUC, and FARM Coordinates For: ", farm.metadata$farm.name, sep=""))
legend("bottomright", legend = c("Farm","Merra points","Ruc points-closest","Ruc points"))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the same error showing even putting pch outside legend. coords = cbind(lon=c(farm.metadata$coordinates["Longitude"],merraLoc$Global.Longitude,ruc.points$Global.Longitude),
     lat=c(farm.metadata$coordinates["Latitude"],merraLoc$Global.Latitude,ruc.points$Global.Latitude))
rownames(coords) = c(farm,rep("MERRA",4),rep("RUC",4))
write.csv(coords,paste(out.path,"coords.csv",sep="/"))

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the same error showing even putting pch outside legend.

Comment: Hi, the synthax seems correct, could you provide a reproductible example ?

Comment: plot(c(farm.metadata$coordinates["Longitude"],merraLoc$Global.Longitude,ruc.points$Global.Longitude),
+      c(farm.metadata$coordinates["Latitude"],merraLoc$Global.Latitude,ruc.points$Global.Latitude),
+      xlab="Latitude",ylab="Longitude", 
+      legend("bottomright",c("Farm","Merra points","Ruc points-closest","Ruc points")),
+      pch=c(9,rep(19,4),20,rep(4,3)),
+       .....
Error in plot.xy(xy, type, ...) : invalid plot type

Comment: Thanks Mamoun. It's a part of a code. It's going to draw 9 points, the first is the farm location, then 4 merra points, then the closest ruc point, followed by 3 closer ruc points. Merra and Ruc points are obtained by another function which has no problem. If only using pch and delete legend, everything is fine. With legend, it has such an error.

Comment: Here's ruc point data. Merra data is similar.

ruc.points = find.closest.model.points(farm.metadata$coordinates["Longitude"], farm.metadata$coordinates["Latitude"], "RUCG130", n = 4)
ruc.points
#  Global.I Global.J Global.Longitude Global.Latitude Global.Elevation  Distance Data.Start            Data.End
# 1707      195      178         -102.901          40.986         1298.884  3.537408 2010-07-21 2014-04-13 23:00:00

Comment: Ok, can you please try this legend("bottomright", **legend** = c("Farm","Merra points","Ruc points-closest","Ruc points"))

Comment: Mamoun, get the same error again with legend("bottomright", legend = c("Farm","Merra points","Ruc points-closest","Ruc points"))

Comment: Hi, just found the problem and changed the answer. the **legend** should be simply outside the **plot**, that is all.